# Issues with Serilog's Destructure.ByTransforming skipping log statements involving that type

Tags: vb.net, elasticsearch, logging, serilog

We're using Serilog + Elasticsearch as a logging solution.  I've been attempting to add logging to a legacy project which uses DB2 as the back end.  As such, I am attempting to add the argument list of type `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Parameter` to the Debug logs before a stored procedure is ran.  I first tried the built in Destructuring:

`_logger.Debug("{@Args}", args)`

Where args is an array of `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Parameter`.  When I do this, the log message is skipped and does not appear at all.  If I change it to `{Args}` instead, I get the predicable `["IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Parameter", "IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Parameter", ... ]`.

I then tried adding a custom destructure as noted [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data#customizing-the-stored-data) as I only really wanted a few things from `iDB2Parameter` like name, type, size, and value:

`.Destructure.ByTransforming(Of IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Parameter)(Function(x) New With {.ParameterName = x.ParameterName, .Type = x.iDB2DbType, .Size = x.Size, .Value = x.Value})`

However, this just produced the same results as before.  Am I missing a key step?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you're looking to log some value before the SP is executed, yet you're running into issues with the logging itself.  One you're SP isn't executing or is failing, so I wonder if the error is actually somewhere in the stack before the execution of the procedure/method/function that calls the SP execution.  Hope it helps, not too familiar with this space.

Comment: I'm logging the `iDB2Parameter` collection of arguments before the stored procedure is ran, so any SP related errors are probably out of the running.  I set up the custom Destructure because I only care about the few `iDB2Parameter` parameters listed.  It is my understanding that when you set up a custom Destructure any time the type that was set up is seen by Serilog it applies the rules you set up in the Destructure.

Comment: Okay this sounds more of a database type question than code.  I was viewing it from a completely different view.  My mistake good luck.